# I am getting a error im not sure of it is poor syntax or if i am restricted

Tags: mysql

I am joining two tables one has a composite key `customer_order`

This is the syntax I used is it ok to try select the second PK from the composite key with a comma?

`SELECT cus.first_name, cus.last_name, co.order_id 
FROM customer cus LEFT JOIN cust_order co ON cus.cust_id = co.order_id, co.cust_id;`

I get this error message

`ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 's2981938'@'localhost' for table 'cust_id'`

I know it says I am denied but is this because of bad syntax or am i restricted

Because when I use this synatx

`SELECT cus.first_name, cus.last_name, co.order_id 
FROM customer cus LEFT JOIN cust_order co ON cus.cust_id = co.order_id;`

I get the first and last name but the order id is null for all rows???

Comment: So why can I use the `SELECT` command the second time and get the result with null?, could you restrict exact syntax commands?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't read your first statement carefully enough. You do in fact have a syntax erorr (`ON cus.cust_id = co.order_id, co.cust_id` is not valid SQL; the comma and what's after don't belong there). This is a syntax error that MySQL is handling poorly.

Comment: It looks like the account you're using doesn't have permissions to read the `cust_id` table, but is that even a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your first query and its not working

```
SELECT cus.first_name, cus.last_name, co.order_id 
FROM customer cus LEFT JOIN cust_order co ON cus.cust_id = co.order_id, co.cust_id;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z)

Your `2nd` query seems not correct. You should be joining these tables based on `cust_id`. Use `join` to show only those `customers` with `orders`.

```
select cus.first_name, cus.last_name, co.order_id 
FROM customer cus 
inner join cust_order co ON cus.cust_id = co.cust_id
```